# C# function destroy doesn't function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

So I'm trying to make a 2D Snake game in Unity, which is made from 4 different C# scripts.

In this particular I try to delete the Food which the snake eats but nothing happens (Its marked in the Code), and the other function works just fine. I don't even get an Error.

If you need the other scripts, I can send those as well.

```
public void SnakeMoved(Vector2Int snakeGridPosition)
{
    if (snakeGridPosition == foodGridPosition)
    {
        Object.Destroy(foodGameObject);
        SpawnFood();
    }
}
```

I tried to see if the rest in the IF clause works and the rest is working perfectly. I don't know what I did wrong.

Code for the foodGameObject:

```
private void SpawnFood() 
{
    foodGridPosition = new Vector2Int(Random.Range(0, width), Random.Range(0, height));
    
    GameObject foodGameObject = new GameObject("Food", typeof(SpriteRenderer));
    foodGameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = GameAssets.i.foodSprite;
    foodGameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(foodGridPosition.x, foodGridPosition.y);
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working - in other words why do you think that the gameobject isn't destroyed?

Comment: The gameObject is the "Food" which the Snake should eat, after the Food gets eaten it should disapper from the field. But i can still see it.

Comment: Please complete the question by adding the part that initiates the `foodGameObject`. Even though it's quite an obvious guess.

Comment: It could be floating point issues with the positions where 3,2 is not the same as 3,2.00000001 it could be the new food is spawning where the old food was. It could be a lot of things

Comment: What object type is `foodGameObject`? `GameObject` or `MonoBehaviour`?

Comment: @BugFinder It's an int vector, there is no floating point issue.

Comment: Add `Debug.Log(“Destroying food”, foodGameObject);` this will allow you to highlight your object in hierarchy from the console line and see if you are targeting the object you are expecting.

Comment: @ephb sadly i dont get a response, seems like the DebugLog doesn't work.

Comment: If adding it before your ```Object.Destroy(foodGameObject);``` line does not work then that code is not being reached.

Comment: @ephb but why would the SpawnFood function work if rest isn't?

Comment: I could only guess with not seeing more of your class. But this line would give you a line in the console that says "Destroying food" even if the second parameter is null. If it does not it is not being reached.
You should debug your code and set break point at different points to see what is being reached and what is not. [Tutorial](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Unity you cannot create game objects in code using  `new GameObject(...)`. Instead you need to instantiate these, like that:

`GameObject instantiatedFood = Instantiate(new GameObject("Food", typeof(SpriteRenderer)));`

Instead of `new GameObject("Food", typeof(SpriteRenderer))` you could also pass a prefab here which you link in the editor.

This instantiation step makes sense because you can prepare and deal with GameObjects in code before actually spawning them in the world.

Comment: Thank you for your input but sadly it doesen't work. after i apply the changes i get a null referece exeption for this line (for snakeGridPosition). Do you maybe know why?

Comment: I updated my answer after you added the additional code snippet. Hopefully it is more helpful now :)